# Can't find newly added stocks in searchView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, searchview

So this is not an error I am getting or anything. It is an implementation that I am having a hard time doing.

I made a stock app where you can search for stocks from an API and add them to a recyclerView. I have also implemented a searchView to find any certain stock on my recyclerView list.

However, this is my problem: Let's say I opened the app and added a new stock to the list from the API. It adds the stock perfectly to the list. However, when I go to the searchView to find that same stock I just added, I cannot find it in the searchView list. In fact, that certain stock ALSO gets deleted from the recyclerView list (where it existed perfectly right before I went into searchView). When I restart the app, that's when the stock shows up in the recyclerView list again and this time I can access it from searchView list. It's just a weird thing that's happening.

This problem only happens if I try to find a stock that I just added to my list and want to find it in the searchView right after. If I close the app and reopen, that's when the searchView knows that the stock exists. Otherwise, it just seems to not know whenever a new stock is being added.

Please help!

**Adapter class w/ Filter implementation:**

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {
MainActivity mainAct;
List<Stock> stocks;
List<Stock> searchAllStocks;

Adapter(MainActivity ma, List<Stock> stocks) {
    this.mainAct = ma;
    this.stocks = stocks;
    this.searchAllStocks = new ArrayList<>(stocks);
}
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return stockFilter;
}
private Filter stockFilter = new Filter() {
    //runs on background thread
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) { //charSequence constraint is whatever is typed into search
        List<Stock> filteredList = new ArrayList<Stock>(); //list to store only filtered items

        if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) { //if nothing in input field
            filteredList.addAll(searchAllStocks); //show all stocks on filteredList
        }
        else { //else get user input and convert into string to filter
            String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for(Stock item: searchAllStocks) { //for each stock item in
                if(item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) { //add items that match to filteredList
                    filteredList.add(item);
                }
                if(item.getSymbol().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) { //add items that match to filteredList
                    filteredList.add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        //returns FilterResults and gets passed to publishResults
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filteredList;

        return results;
    }
    //runs on UI thread
    //clears current stock list and adds results of user's search to list
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        stocks.clear();
        stocks.addAll((List)results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

**Method executed in MainActivity when search button is pressed:**

```
//if search button is pressed
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.search) {
        //set up new toolbar for searching
        searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();
        searchView.onActionViewExpanded(); //expands search bar
        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE); //sets keyboard icon to done after user types
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search...");


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            //does stuff after text submitted
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            //does stuff in realtime
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

**This is where I think my problem is**

**This method is called after retrieving info from AsyncTask class**

```
//update Stock list on screen w/ info passed from Async class AsyncStockDownloader
public void updateData(Stock stock) {
    boolean flag = false;

    //check for duplicate stocks on list
    for(int i = 0; i < stocks.size(); i++) {
        if(stocks.get(i).getSymbol().equals(stock.getSymbol())) {
            //create alertbox
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(stock.getSymbol() + " is already displayed!");
            builder.setTitle("Duplicate Stock");

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    //if no duplicate then add to list, database, and notify adapter that we changed
    if(!flag) {
        stocks.add(stock);
        db.addStock(stock);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //problem is here. we need to let searchAllStocks in adapter know when stock is added
        //so that searchbar can store new stock into searchAllStocks
    }
}
```

Please do let me know if there's any other code I need to post. These are only snippets of where I think the problem may lie.

Thank you guys in advance!

----------------------------------------edit--------------------------------------

**This is the method called after receiving info from Asynctask**

**I have added 1 line of code to try and solve the problem: adapter.searchAllStocks.add(...) as comments have suggested**

**These are the results**

```
//update Stock list on screen w/ info passed from Async class AsyncStockDownloader
public void updateData(Stock stock) {
    boolean flag = false;

    //check for duplicate stocks on list
    for(int i = 0; i < stocks.size(); i++) {
        if(stocks.get(i).getSymbol().equals(stock.getSymbol())) {
            adapter.searchAllStocks.clear();
            //create alertbox
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(stock.getSymbol() + " is already displayed!");
            builder.setTitle("Duplicate Stock");

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    //if no duplicate then add to list, database, and notify adapter that we changed
    if(!flag) {
        stocks.add(stock);
        adapter.searchAllStocks.add(new Stock(stock.getSymbol(), stock.getName(), stock.getLatestPrice(), stock.getChange(), stock.getChangePercent()));
        db.addStock(stock);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //problem is here. we need to let searchAllStocks in adapter know when stock is added
        //so that searchbar can store new stock into searchAllStocks list
    }
}
```

So now let me run u through what my app looks like.

**1. This is homepage where I added 3 stocks already**

[image]

**2. I clicked on the search option from toolbar to find a stock named "GOOG"**

[image]

The filteredList also shows 2 GOOG stocks which is weird, I would prefer it to show 1 but don't know why this is happening.

**3. This is the filteredList that shows after I clear my whole searchBar. As you can see, there is a duplicate stock for each stock.**

[image]

**4. Now when I press back to revert to the home page, I am left with all these duplicate stocks from my filteredList. Obviously we don't want that**

[image]

**5. However, when I refresh my homepage I get my beautiful single stocks back again. I would love to see my stocks show up like this page after I press the back button every time**

[image]

Thanks again anyone!

Comment: You only have updated **stocks** by `stocks.add(stock)` but also need a method to update **searchAllStocks**. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I have added the line: 
"adapter.searchAllStocks.add(stock);" 
after the stocks.add(stock) part. However, the problem w/ this is that now I get duplicate stocks on my list. 
My list can only contain 1 type of each stock. However, when I also add the stock to searchAllStocks, it seems to be adding it to that list and resulting in me seeing 2 lists with many duplicate stocks - 1 list for stocks.add() and 1 list for searchAllStocks.add(). 

Any idea on how to fix this bug? Thanks again!

Comment: I cannot fully understand your comment, may be you add images for explanantion. Also I think that a seperate object is needed, so create a new Stock object and save it to the searchAllStocks. Therefore use `adapter.searchAllStocks.add(new Stock(stock.getName(), stock.get...));` instead of `adapter.searchAllStocks.add(stock);`. Hope that helps!

Comment: I have edited my original post above and shared the screenshots. Please do have a look and let me know if it is enough information for you to evaluate. Thank you so much, really appreciate you taking the time! I have also added the line of code like you have suggested but still have same problem

Comment: Your problem is weird. From the posted code, I don't find any error. My suggestion is to add Log to every line [from before stocks.add(stock) to after db.add(stock)] to monitor the size of searchAllStocks. Therefore we get 4 numbers that should be helpful to analysis the problem. On the other hand, if you comment out the newly added code [adapter.searchAllStocks.add()], does the app go back to your original issue?

Comment: Yes, the app goes back to the original issue. Before adding the line, the problem was that the recently added stock would not show on my searchView list. However, after adding the line u have suggested, now the problem is that the stock shows multiple times on my searchView list hahah

Comment: Hey I solved the problem. Thank you for taking the time to help! Much appreciated!